# Get value from method from each item in ArrayList as an Array

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList<ROI2D>`, ROI2D contains a `getName();` method that returns a string.

I now want these names to show up in a `JComboBox` so that the user may select a ROI2D based on the name.

Using `ArrayList.toArray();` will get the Array[x] of ROI2Ds, but can I perform `.getName();` on it somehow and pass that to JComboBox? Or is the only way to create a separate Array containing the Names, and using comparisons afterwards to see which ROI2D the user selected?

Comment: I think overwriting the `toString` method should do the trick

Comment: Can you show your code? Explain the situation better? Currently your question is **unclear**. The best description would probably be to show the code.

Comment: Use `objectList.stream().map(s -> s.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you actually need to do, is to simply overwrite the `toString()` method to just return the name. I made a simple example to show it:

main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    List<Client> cs = new ArrayList();

    cs.add(new Client("Hans", 1));
    cs.add(new Client("Peter", 2));
    JComboBox c = new JComboBox<Client>(cs.toArray(new Client[] {}));

    c.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            System.out.println(((Client) e.getItem()).getAge());
        }

    });

    f.add(c);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);

}
```

And the `Client` class:

```
public class Client {

    String name;

    int age;

    public Client(String n, int age) {
        name = n;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }

}
```

This works perfectly find. Each entry in the `JComboBox` only shows the name

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8 you can use Streams API.

```
List<String> stringList = 
             roid2dList.stream().map(n -> n.getName).collect(Collectors.toList());

String[] stringArray = new String[stringList.size()];
stringArray = stringList.toArray(stringArray);
```

See more examples here:
https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-map-examples/

Comment: You do realize that an array is explicitly needed?

Comment: Sure. But I thought that converting a List to an array in Java should be common sense. I've edited my answer and added the code.

Comment: And to further clarify, he wants the actual objects to be added to the `JComboBox` but only show the name